# NuGet Pack VersionSchemes Want a major.minor.date.run scheme

Tags: nuget, version, azure-pipelines

I am having difficulty getting this to work.

I am extracting major and minor from AssemblyInfo.

I am not able to figure out how to extract the Date and run number.

I am blind because I cannot see the pipeline varables.

## Thanks Andy

I have tried to create a variable named packedversion as you suggested.

I added the following task to YAML

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Set packversion number
      
      $packageversion = '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Major).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Minor).$(Build.BuildNumber)'
      echo 'packageversion: $packageversion'
      Write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageversion]$packageversion"
      echo 'Major: $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Major)'
      echo 'Minor: $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Minor)'
      echo 'buildNum: $(Build.BuildNumber)'
      echo 'completed packageversion: $(packageversion)'
```

The results data echoed from the PowerShell is :

```
packageversion: $packageversion
Major: 0
Minor: 15
buildNum: 20200722.8
completed packageversion: $(packageversion)
```

Please point me to a description of what this syntax does

> ```
>   Write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageversion]$packageversion"
> ```

Then changed the nuget pack to:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack JRTestLib'
  inputs:
      command: pack
      packagesToPack: JLReyLibrary/JRTestLib/JRTestLib.csproj
      versioningScheme: byEnvVar
      versionEnvVar: $(packageversion)
      includeSymbols: true
      toolPackage: true
  enabled: true
```

The nuget task says it cannot fine provided environment variable.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I updated the answer, please check it and see the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to figure out how to extract the Date and run number.

The simplest way is using the predefined run (build) number variable : `$(Build.BuildNumber)`

The default value for run number is `$(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)`. Please refer to [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for details. It already includes the `date` in the run number. So, the requested scheme can be `$(major).$(minor).$(Build.BuildNumber)`

Please follow below steps to do that :

1. We can use the extension [Assembly Info Reader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kherzog.AssemblyInfoReader) to read the
   assembly attributes from the `AssemblyInfo` file and makes them
   available as build variables.
2. Add a Powershell task in your pipeline to set custom variable
   `$packageversion` using logging command :

   `$packageversion = "$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Major).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Minor).$(Build.BuildNumber)"`

   `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageversion]$packageversion"`
3. Use the variable `packageversion`in NuGet pack task: (`Pack Options -> Use an environment variable -> packageversion` )
   [image]
4. Publish to the specific Artifact feed.
   [image]

**Update:**

Yaml for your reference :

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set packageversion variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "AssemblyVersion:" $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion)
      Write-Host "Major:" $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Major)
      Write-Host "Minor:" $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Minor)
      Write-Host "BuildNumber:" $(Build.BuildNumber)
      $packageversion = "$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Major).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Minor).$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      Write-Host "packageversion:" $packageversion
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageversion]$packageversion"
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: NuGet pack
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'packageversion'
```

The syntax `Write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageversion]$packageversion"` is for setting the variable `packageversion` here. After defined the variables, we can use them in the subsequent tasks within the same session. Reference this thread for details: [Azure DevOps - Setting and Using Variables in PowerShell Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333871/azure-devops-setting-and-using-variables-in-powershell-scripts)

Comment: @jl-rey Have your resolved the issue by following the above steps? Any update here?

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

The final problem was as follows:

The use of nuget pack with the byEnvVar option

The versionEnvVar takes the name of the variable not the variable value.

Note: this is different than the byPrerelease option that accepts values.

I am still having difficulties with defining and seeing variables but that is a different topic.

Thanks for the help